# How can I merge results from multiple REST endpoints?

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, axios

I am new to Express.

I am creating a new API endpoint, which is getting data from two other publically available endpoints. Once I get the JSON from both APIs, I will merge them according to some rules.

```
let result1, result2;

// API 1
let data1;
app.get("/test1", (req, res, next) => {
  axios.get("https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_A")
  .then((response) => {
     res.json(response.data)
     data1 = response.data;
  });
});

// API 2
let data2;
app.get("/test2", (req, res, next) => {
  axios.get("https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_B")
  .then((response) => {
     res.json(response.data)
     data2 = response.data;
  });
});

console.log(data1); //output is undefined
console.log(data2); //output is undefined
```

I can see result of successful calls in both the browser and in Postman.

My problem is, that I cannot find a way to manipulate the result of each endpoint. I have tried to store like this `result1 = response.data` in the `then` but it is `undefined`. Once I can *access* the output of each response, then I have to merge them. But accessing the results outside the `axios` call appears to be more difficult. I don't have to use `axios`.

I also tried this but it didn't work.

```
// API 1
const data1 = app.get("/test1", (req, res, next) => {
  axios.get("https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_A")
  .then((response) => res.json(response.data));
});

console.log(data1); //output is undefined
```

Comment: It's probably undefined because you're not returning anything. Post all of what you tried

Comment: @Phix I see the entire JSON output in browser and Postman.

Comment: @Phix I've added what did not work. Please let me know if it makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

as far as im aware data does not persist between api calls. you could combine that into a single endpoint.

```js
//Both apis into one endpoint
app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  const promiseArr = [axios.get('https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_A'), 
                      axios.get('https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_B')];
  Promise.all(promiseArr).then(responses => {
    const resultsFromEndpointA = responses[0];
    const resultsFromEndpointB = responses[1];
    //do what you want with your results here... for example.. 
    return res.status(200).json({resultsFromEndpointA, resultsFromEndpointB});
    
    //or do something like load them into a session
    req.session.results = {resultsFromEndpointA, resultsFromEndpointB};
    next();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: I mean I'm gonna need to see your code to understand why... as far as a standalone endpoint goes unless its hitting the catch it should be resolving with either res.... or moving to next.. next should only be called if you have something to go on to. such as if this was a middleware function you'd call next typically

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an array of objects with the same properties from the both endpoints, do this;

```
let results = [];

// API 1
app.get("/test1", (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_A"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      results.push(response.data);
    });
});

// API 2
app.get("/test2", (req, res, next) => {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://www.EXAMPLE.com/api/endpoint_B"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      results.push(response.data);
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but when call the api, `console.log(results);` does not show anything.